# Using ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool effective

Tags: asp.net, authorization, roles

I want to control authorization in my asp.net project but I am little confused.
what is the best way to use ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool effective?
is it a good idea to create directories for every pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the few articles on **Role Based Security**

1. [**How To Implement Role-Based Security with Forms-Based Authentication in Your ASP.NET Application by Using Visual C# .NET**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311495)
2. [**[ASP.NET Membership] Role-Based Security**](http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/role-based-security/)
3. [**Designing Role-Based Security Models for .NET**](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c19575/Designing-Role-Based-Security-Models-for-NET.htm)
4. [**Role-based Security with Forms Authentication**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication)